# match first vowel in each word of a string and print them comma-separated with regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, findall

here's what I have so far

```
my_str = "The sky's the limit"

regex = re.findall(r"\b\w*?[aeiouAEIOU]", my_str)
joined_str = ", ".join(regex)

print(joined_str)
```

and I want it to print

```
e, e, i
```

but it prints

```
The, the, li
```

so how do I ignore the previous characters of the word with a vowel and just print the first vowel of each word and separate the vowels by commas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to restrict the part of the expression you want returned, by encapsulating it in a capture group:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\b\w*?([aeiouAEIOU])", my_str)
['e', 'e', 'i']
```

The `()` tells the regular expression engine to only return matches for the expression within the `()`.

Comment: thanks burhan! another question as I'd rather not dedicate a whole different thread for another one of these small questions. how can I go about using the re.sub() function to replace all of the occurrences of 'the' and 'The' with 'a' in a string?

Comment: `re.sub(r'[T|t]he', 'a', my_str)`

Comment: I think your above code would also match words like "them", "there", and "then" but I would like it to only match to the word "the". any way to prevent it from matching these other words that start with "the"? apologies for not specifying this

Comment: Ah yea, just surround it with a word boundary `re.sub(r'\b[T|t]he\b', 'a', my_str)`

Answer (score 0):

If you can do without regex, you could do it, like so:

```
def find_first_vowel(s):
    first_vowels = ''
    for word in s.split():        
        for index, char in enumerate(word):            
            if char in 'aeiouAEIOU':    # you can check the index here                
                first_vowels += char                
                break
    return ', '.join(first_vowels)

my_str = "The sky's the limit"

>>> print(find_first_vowel(my_str))
e, e, i
```